# Postfix for use with Django

Tags: ubuntu, email, smtp

I have a default Ubuntu 13.04 install on which I'm running a simple web game using Django. I need to be able to send email from that and the forums I'm using, I don't need to receive any mail or indeed any advanced functionality at all.

I've attempted about 5 times to install Postfix (I'd prefer not to use third-party SMTP servers) and every single time nothing works. I've tried following the null client sample config, I've tried following several guides on the internet and I'm at my wits' end.

The install works, then I try using `sendmail` from terminal and it hangs.
I also do `sudo postfix start` and it tells me that it cannot bind to port 25, upon which I check what is running on that port and find sendmail. I do `apt-get remove sendmail*` and it *still* says that it cannot bind to that port.

Could someone give me a simple, step by step, idiot-proof guide to the simplest selfcontained way of sending email from a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As precaution execute as root `apt-get -s remove sendmail.*`. If something may be remove then repeat the command without `-s` (dry run).
2. You may use `fuser -kuv 25/tcp` to kill all processes listening on port 25 (smtp). The command is provided by `psmisc` Debian package.

Comment: 1. Found nothing, I had already done `sudo apt-get remove sendmail*`

2. returns 
'$ fuser -kuv tcp/25
Specified filename tcp/25 does not exist.'

Comment: 1. `.` before `*` is IMPORTANT 2. I have fixed argument format: `tcp/25` -> `25/tcp`

Comment: 1: Still found nothing.
2: Solved my problem, thank you so much!! Why did this happen? How do I prevent this happening again?